# Issues with Postfix as forwarding server

Tags: email, postfix, mail-forwarding

Trying to set Postfix up as a mail forwarding server. Here's the relevant (I think) bits of my config;

#### /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
inet_interfaces = 94.23.155.113
[...]
mydestination = sams-blog.net
[...]
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/urlatron/mail/maptest
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/var/urlatron/mail/domains
```

#### /var/urlatron/mail/maptest

```
sam@sams-blog.net samarudge@gmail.com
```

#### /var/urlatron/mail/domains

```
sams-blog.net
```

When sending an email to 'sam@sams-blog.net' using GMail (A seperate account from the one I'm trying to send to), I get absolutely nothing back, not even a failure. From the looks of it, GMail thinks the message has been delivered successfully. Using https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server I get the following

```
Resolving hostname...
Connecting...
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
220 oncilla.customermail.urlatron.com URLATRON Inc. Mail Forwarding Server, abuse requests should be sent to abuse@urlatron.com or phone +1 415 625 0043, URLATRON Inc. takes no responsibility for the contents of messages sent by this server.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
250-oncilla.customermail.urlatron.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: sam@rmg.io
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 
RCPT TO: sam@sams-blog.net
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 
Message sending failed.
```

I don't have a /var/log/mail.log (Which is apparently where PostFix does it's debugging, but apparently not). I do have /var/log/maillog but that's empty.

How do I go about debugging this? Is there anything blazingly obvious I've missed out? The eventual aim is to get PostFix to use MySQL as a source for it's aliases but I figured I'd try and get it working with a flat hash file to start.

My full main.cf file is [here](https://gist.github.com/649da9be536688c26eb8), incase I missed anything important out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think there is something wrong with either the name resolution timeouts or your entire machine. When I try `telnet 94.23.155.113 25`, this is the SMTP dialogue I can get:

```
220 oncilla.customermail.urlatron.com URLATRON Inc. Mail Forwarding Server, abuse requests should be sent to abuse@urlatron.com or phone +1 415 625 0043, URLATRON Inc. takes no responsibility for the contents of messages sent by this server.
helo bla
502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
helo bla
250 oncilla.customermail.urlatron.com
mail from:<dj@syneticon.net>
```

and there it ends and hangs indefinitely - no further response to the "mail from:" command.

When looking for your logs, check the syslog configuration (typically /etc/syslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.d) - postfix does not write to log files itself but uses syslog instead. Also try restarting the syslog daemon and postfix - just in case logrotate managed to kill your logging features due to misconfiguration.

Comment: *facepalm* Looked in syslog and it was logging to a really weird location, looked in the logs and turns out all I needed to do was update the aliases with `postalias`